# Can I create App Pool on IIS7 using wix if IIS6 Management Compatibility is not installed

Tags: iis-7, wix, wix3.5, application-pool

I know that there is the native IIS7 support in wix 3.5, but I have this strange error. 
So, if IIS6 Management Compatibility for IIS7 is not installed, then new App Pool did not created in installation process. But if IIS6 MC is installed it works ok and new App Pool is created. The name of App Pool we define in dialog during installation.

This wix code is used for define app poll:

```
<IIs:WebAppPool Id="AppPoolId" Name="[APP_POOL_NAME]" />
```

This error I have if IIS6 MC for IIS7 is not installed:

```
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x800700b7: Failed to add appPool element
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x800700b7: Failed to configure IIS appPool.
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x800700b7: WriteIIS7ConfigChanges Failed.
```

Wix version is Wix3.5.2519.0

Comment: I forgot about the main (ask question:)). Is this a bug? Or I need use some other tag for app pool's definition in wix?

Comment: I too faced the same problem and so I wrote C# custom action to create virtual directory, application pool and then binding the virtual dir to the app pool.

Comment: Yes, I thought about custom action for it. Probably, I will go this way too, because don't see another for the present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound like a bug. Please open bug with details here: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=105970&atid=642714

Comment: I opened bug for it. Its number is 3316654 ("It's impossible to create App Pool on IIS7 using wix").